# Chef manage reports from command line

Tags: linux, chef-infra, ubuntu-14.04, chef-recipe

I have a bounch of nodes in my chef orgianization, and I right now to know if something is wrong I have to go through the GUI to check reportings if the runs of the nodes have gone OK. However, I am wondering if it is possible to retrieve the data of failures from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the knife-reporting plugin, https://docs.chef.io/plugin_knife_reporting.html.

Comment: Alright, so thereis no built-in functionality for this?

Comment: I mean that's a knife plugin, not sure what else you're looking for. I don't know off hand if we ship it with ChefDK but it's one `chef gem install` command if we don't.